# If almost every element of $E$ is contained in at least $k$ sets from $\{E_1,...,E_m\}$, show $\mu(E_\ell)\geq \frac{k}{m}\mu(E)$ for some $\ell$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{E_1,...,E_m\}$ be Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $1\leq k\leq m$ a natural number. Suppose that $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\mu(E)>0$ and is such that for almost all $x\in E$, we have that $x$ is in at least $k$ of the $E_j$. Show that there is an index $\ell$ such that $\mu(E_\ell)\geq \frac{k}{m}\mu(E)$. Here we use $\mu$ for Lebesgue measure.

My attempt is to define $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^m \chi_{E_j}(x)$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function. Then $f(x)$ is Lebesgue measurable and by hypothesis we have that $f(x)\geq k$ almost everywhere on $E$. Then
\begin{equation} \int_E fd\mu\geq k\mu(E).\end{equation}
On the other hand by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have
\begin{equation} \int_E fd\mu=\sum_{j=1}^m \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \chi_E\cdot \chi_{E_j}d\mu\leq \sum_{j=1}^m \sqrt{\mu(E_j)\mu(E)}\leq \sqrt{\mu(E)}\sqrt{m}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^m\mu(E_j)}.\end{equation}
Then we get that
\begin{equation}
\frac{k^2}{m}\mu(E)\leq \sum_{j=1}^m \mu(E_j).\end{equation}
Unfortunately, doing the obvious thing which is to suppose that $\mu(E_j)<\frac{k}{m}\mu(E)$ for all $1\leq j\leq m$ does not get you a contradiction here. If someone could help me either make this argument work with a more robust inequality than Cauchy-Schwarz or suggest a better strategy for doing this question that would be excellent! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily there is no need for Cauchy-Schwartz. By shrinking $E_j$, we may assume $E_j \subset E$ and then the integrals of the intersections in your sum are $\mu(E_j)$. Now at least one of those $m$ numbers has to be greater than (or equal to) the average of the numbers, which by the part you've already calculated is $\frac{k}{m} \mu(E)$.